# How to pass an embedded image in an include template

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

Okay so I came upon a complicated problem to which I can't seem to find any solution online.

To put things simply, I have a twig file with an embedded picture `Branding`, which is used like that:

```
<img src="cid:Branding" alt='branding' />
```

That "Branding" picture doesn't have a fixed address and is passed to the twig file on email creation, with the `embed()` function as follows:

```
$email = (new Email())
                ->from(...)
                ->to(...)
                ->subject(...)
                ->embed($branding['content'], 'Branding', $branding['mimeType'])
```

The part above works. The "Branding" image is displayed through the twig file, and everything goes fine.

Now, I also need to use this image in the template used for the footer. My problem is the following:

When I use this:

```
{% include 'email/footer.html.twig' with {'Branding': Branding} %}
```

I get an error saying it doesn't know the "Branding" variable

When I use this:

```
{% include 'email/footer.html.twig' with {'Branding': cid:Branding} %}
```

I get an error saying it can't parse the ":" character.

I considered trying to set a variable for the image too, but I get the same parsing error.

```
{% set Branding = cid:Branding %}
{% include 'email/footer.html.twig' with {'Branding': Branding} %}
```

I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do is possible (in that case, would you suggest anything else?). The [twig documentation about includes](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html) only covers text variables as examples so it's not very useful with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How do you define that? If there is no Twig variable named `Branding`, it's obvious you cannot access it. Why not create a variable in that case?

Comment: `Branding` is an embedded file included with `(new Email())->embed($branding['content'], 'Branding', $branding['mimeType'])` in my php class creating the email. I was trying to access the embed from the included template directly, maybe I can try to set a variable beforehands, I'll try and edit the question accordingly

Comment: Please add all explanation to your question by editing it. What do you mean by "embedded file"? How did you add it to the Twig template?

Comment: question edited, does it need more details (and regarding which part?)

Comment: Unsure, but if `src="cid:Branding"` actually returns an image, then this conversion is not done by twig. Did you try to just use `src="cid:Branding"` in the footer?

Comment: I don't think you need to "pass" anything to your footer template here. Just put `<img src="cid:Branding" alt='branding' />` into it, same as you are using it in your main template. `cid:foo` is syntax used by email clients, to render that image from a file _attached_ to the email - and that attaching happened using your `embed` method call. Your twig template itself is not accessing any variables, regarding `<img src="cid:Branding" alt='branding' />` Your template does not need to replace `cid:Branding` with anything - this needs to be that same literal _text_ in your actual email content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this is not exactly the solution I was looking for, but I managed to make it work by importing twice the image from the php file.

NOTE:
Doing the embed twice from the same image didn't work for me and made both images to fail displaying

```
$email = (new Email())
                ->from(...)
                ->to(...)
                ->subject(...)
                ->embed($branding['content'], 'branding', $branding['mimeType'])
                ->embed($branding['content'], 'brandingFooter', $branding['mimeType'])
```

I managed to make it work by importing the image from two different places, like this:

```
$email = (new Email())
                ->from(...)
                ->to(...)
                ->subject(...)
                ->embed($branding['content'], 'branding', $branding['mimeType'])
                ->embedFromPath("{$this->projectDirectory}/media/logo.png", 'footerBranding')
```

I still don't understand clearly why I couldn't use the same image twice in the same email, but I managed to get a solution so I'll tag this as the answer.